# Stretch height with flexbox align-items center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div with `display: flex; flex-direction: row;`. The children of this div take the full height unless I specify `align-items: center`. Code below -

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: beige;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.row2 {
  align-items: center;
}

.row-item {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.item1,
.item3 {
  width: 100px;
}

.item2 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row1">
  <div class="row-item item1">1</div>
  <div class="row-item item2">
    <div> 2.1 </div>
    <div> 2.2 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-item item3">3</div>
</div>

<div class="row row2">
  <div class="row-item item1">1</div>
  <div class="row-item item2">
    <div> 2.1 </div>
    <div> 2.2 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-item item3">3</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaibatrik/12un9p37/3/)

What I want to achieve is that 2.1 and 2.2 should take 50px (50%) height and should have its content middle aligned vertically. They should also stretch the full available space horizontally (like width: auto or 100%). Then if 2.1 is not present, 2.2 should take 100px height and should be vertically aligned to middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make row-items a flex box and apply `align-items: center;` to them

This is the code that you should add

```
.row1 .row-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

See result below :

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: beige;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.row2 {
  align-items: center;
}

.row-item {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.row1 .row-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row1 .row-item div {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item1,
.item3 {
  width: 100px;
}

.item2 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row1">
  <div class="row-item item1">1</div>
  <div class="row-item item2">
    <div> 2.1 </div>
    <div> 2.2 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-item item3">3</div>
</div>

<div class="row row2">
  <div class="row-item item1">1</div>
  <div class="row-item item2">
    <div> 2.1 </div>
    <div> 2.2 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-item item3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I want any div which is inside the row items to be centrally aligned. Do you have any idea how to achieve that. Just updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @jaibatrik do you mean same result as row2 but with full height of row-items?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to achieve; 2.1 and 2.2 should take 50px (50%) height and should have its content middle aligned vertically. They should also stretch the full available space horizontally (like width: auto or 100%).

Comment: Also, if 2.1 is not present, 2.2 should take 100px height and should be vertically aligned to middle.

Comment: @jaibatrik take a look at my edit.. i think it works just like you want :)

Comment: Yes, it appears to be. Thanks, will play around with this for some time!

Comment: @jaibatrik and if you want 1 and 3 to be also centered just wrap them in a div

Answer (score -1):

You can use `line-height` to achieve vertical alignment. In this case since your`.row1` has a height of 100px add the following to that `CSS`: `line-height: 100px;` See the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12un9p37/1/) and for only `.row1` see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5f58sctc/2/)